# how to make rich:upload accept to drag&drop a file from folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, richfaces

I have implemented the file upload using rich:upload tag, now the new requirement is to make it accept drag-drop a file from a folder, then trigger the file upload process.

My question is how to implement this? Regardless Html5, jQuery etc, just implement it.

If it could be integrated to richfaces, e.g. once a drag event received, I can trigger the rich:upload with something like jQuery etc. that is best.

The project web framework is richfaces + jsf.

Thank you in advance.

Addition:
Here is a jquery file upload [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: Try this ,http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Drag_and_drop.html

Comment: I looked this feature before, I am just not sure how to integrate it to <rich:fileupload/>, once an drag event received, how can I trigger it? If could be, that is the best solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://html5demos.com/file-api) you have an example showing how to use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

basically, you have to use the `ondrop` event and the `FileReader` object:

```
<div id='holder'></div>
<script>
    var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
    holder.ondrop = function (e) {
        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
            reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            // your file info
            console.log(event.target);
        };

        // do read
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: how can i use this file in JSF bean

Comment: i dont know JSF, but once you have the file you can try to send it with `xhr.send(File)`

Comment: Yes, we could use xhr.send(File), and also need a new specific method in JSF bean vs the existed one for richfaces, thank you two, it could be a plan B.

Comment: If once an drag event received, how can I trigger the rich:upload? that is the best solution for me.